# Нужны ли запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

Является ли "до этого" обстоятельством времени?

А до этого в 1985 году вместе с женой занимались производством оборудования под давлением.

Answer (score 1):

Да, у нас два подряд обстоятельства времени, но запятая не нужна, так как второе - "в 1985 году" - не уточняет предыдущее обстоятельство - "до этого".

Comment: Мне тоже постановка двух запятых кажется нелепой чисто визуально, но разве нельзя задать вопрос "а до этого" - "Когда именно?" - "В 1985 году"?..

Comment: Я пробовала именно это, прежде чем ответить. ))) У меня не сложилось. 8-( Возможно, дело в разных предлогах. Вот если б было так: "А ДО этого, ДО 1985 года, вместе с женой занимались производством оборудования под давлением", - то таки да.

Comment: Тогда уж лучше тире...

Comment: Тире не нужны, не-а.